# Cube root in Python 3 using Bisection Search: Numbers in -1 to 0

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code, which doesn't seem to work for **numbers in between -1 and 0** (works perfectly fine otherwise)

I think the code enters an infinite loop, somehow, hence I get no result after entering the number. Please have a look and let me know what changes should be made. I am a beginner at programming and would appreciate any help!

```
    cube = float(input('Enter:'))
if abs(cube) > 1:
    num_guesses = 0
    epsilon = 0.0001
    low = 0
    high = cube
    guess = (high + low) / 2.0

    while abs(abs(guess) ** 3 - abs(cube)) >= epsilon:
        if cube > 0:
            if guess ** 3 < cube:
                low = guess
            else:
                high = guess
            guess = (low + high) / 2.0
            num_guesses += 1
        else:
            if guess ** 3 > cube:
                low = guess
            else:
                high = guess
            guess = (low + high) / 2.0
            num_guesses += 1

if abs(cube) < 1:
    num_guesses = 0
    epsilon = 0.0001
    low = cube
    high = 1
    guess = (high + low) / 2.0

    while abs(abs(guess) ** 3 - abs(cube)) >= epsilon:
        if cube > 0:
            if guess ** 3 < cube:
                low = guess
            else:
                high = guess
            guess = (low + high) / 2.0
            num_guesses += 1
        else:
            low = -1
            high = cube
            if guess ** 3 > cube:
                high = guess
            else:
                low = guess
            guess = (low + high) / 2.0
            num_guesses += 1


print(num_guesses)
print('The cube root of',cube,'is closest to',guess)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be simplified by changing the condition to

```
abs(guess ** 3 - cube) >= epsilon
```

In fact, you have to use this condition instead of

```
abs(abs(guess) ** 3 - abs(cube)) >= epsilon
```

since the latter can give false positives (and thus exit the while-loop
prematurely). For example, if `guess` equals 2 and `cube` equals -8, then the
latter condition is True even though 2 is not the cube root of -8.

```
In [65]: guess, cube, epsilon = 2, -8, 0.0001

In [67]: abs(abs(guess) ** 3 - abs(cube)) >= epsilon
Out[67]: False  <-- would cause the while-loop to abort prematurely

In [68]: abs(guess ** 3 - cube) >= epsilon
Out[68]: True
```

---

Notice that in your code sometimes `low` can be bigger than `high`. For example, if `cube < 0`,
then `low` and `high` are initialized this way:

```
if abs(cube) > 1:
    low = 0
    high = cube
```

Especially since we are bisecting, it would helpful if we could rely on `low` always being `<= high`. If we document and abide by a self-imposed **coding contract** that `low <= high`, and if in addition we choose `low` and `high` in such a way so that the cube root is always between `low` and `high`, then the code becomes much much simpler:

```
cube = float(input('Enter:'))

num_guesses = 0
epsilon = 0.0001

# Coding contract: low <= (cube root of cube) <= high
low = min(cube, -1)
high = max(cube, 1)

guess = (high + low) / 2.0

while abs(guess ** 3 - cube) >= epsilon:
    if guess ** 3 < cube:
        low = guess
    else:
        high = guess
    guess = (low + high) / 2.0
    num_guesses += 1

print('num_guesses = {}'.format(num_guesses))
print('The cube root of',cube,'is within epsilon of',guess)
print('{}**3 = {}'.format(guess,guess**3))
```

It is no longer necessary to handle cases for `abs(cube) > 1`, `abs(cube) < 1`, `cube > 0` or `cube <=0`. All values of `cube` can be handled the same way, since `guess**3 - cube` is a monotonically increasing function of `guess`. If `guess**3 > cube`, `guess` is too large so decease `guess`. If `guess**3 < cube`, `guess` is too small so increase guess. The logic of how to adjust `low` and `high` become simple since we know `low <= high`.

---

By the way, in your original code, the

```
else:
    low = -1
    high = cube
```

in the final `else` clause is part of the reason why your code was falling into
an infinite loop.  The `low` and `high` should only be initialized once. Placing
these lines inside the while loop resets `low` and `high` to a wide, naive
interval, and throws away the work done by previous iterations of bisection.

Answer (score 3):

Python_3 implementation of finding cube root using Bisection Method.

You can make functions to simplify it further

```
    x=input("Please Enter a number")
    try:
    cube=float(x)
    except:
        print("Invalid Entry")
```

For number between 0 and 1 or 0 and -1

```
     if (cube>0 and cube<1) or (cube>-1 and cube<0):  
         low=abs(cube)
         high=1
```

For number greater than 1 and less than -1

```
     else:
         if cube>=1 or cube<=-1:
             low=0
             high=abs(cube)
```

Initializing guess using bisection method

```
     guess=(low+high)/2.0
```

Declaring the error margin and calculating the approximate guess(Bisection method)

```
    epsilon=0.001
    while abs(guess**3-abs(cube))>epsilon:
        if guess**3<abs(cube):
            low=guess
        else:
            high=guess
    
        guess=(low+high)/2.0
```

Final output

```
    if cube>0:
        print("The cube root of ",cube,"is",guess)
    else:
        print("The cube root of ",cube,"is",-1*guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script for finding nth roots by bisection search (modified from lecture 4 [here](https://youtu.be/Mx0uXIBD-yA?si=pa86VGI8a5_tvj3I)).

```
def findRoot(pwr, val, epsilon):
    assert type(pwr) == int and type(val) == float and type(epsilon) == float
    assert pwr > 0 and epsilon > 0
    low = 0  
    high = max(abs(val), 1.0)
    pos_ans = (high + low)/2.0
    while abs(pos_ans**pwr - abs(val)) >= epsilon:
        if pos_ans**pwr < abs(val):
            low = pos_ans
        else:
            high = pos_ans
        pos_ans = (high + low)/2.0
    if pwr%2 == 0 and val < 0:
        return None
    elif pwr%2 == 0 and val >= 0:
        return pos_ans
    elif pwr%2 != 0 and val < 0:
        return -pos_ans
    elif pwr%2 != 0 and val >= 0:
        return pos_ans
```

It returns x such that abs(x**pwr - val) <= epsilon.

For example findRoot(5, -0.734, 10**(-5)) returns -0.9400253295898438. Result can be checked by other calculators.

---

Here is a one-line edit, which also prints intervals involved:

```
def findRoot(pwr, val, epsilon):
    assert type(pwr) == int and type(val) == float and type(epsilon) == float
    assert pwr > 0 and epsilon > 0
    low = 0  
    high = max(abs(val), 1.0)
    pos_ans = (high + low)/2.0
    while abs(pos_ans**pwr - abs(val)) >= epsilon:
        if pos_ans**pwr < abs(val):
            low = pos_ans
        else:
            high = pos_ans
        pos_ans = (high + low)/2.0
        print(['low = ' + str(low), 'high = ' + str(high) , 'pos_ans = ' + str(pos_ans)])   
    if pwr%2 == 0 and val < 0:
        return None
    elif pwr%2 == 0 and val >= 0:
        return pos_ans
    elif pwr%2 != 0 and val < 0:
        return -pos_ans
    elif pwr%2 != 0 and val >= 0:
        return pos_ans
```

Here is outcome for findRoot(5, -0.734, 10**(-5)):

[image]